# Deezer audio player after Sept 1 when Chrome start blocking Flash?

Tags: flash, html5-audio, deezer

From the 1st Sept Chrome will start blocking Flash based ads by default:
https://plus.google.com/+GoogleAds/posts/2PmwKinJ7nj

With Flash on its way out does Deezer have a pure HTML5 based web player in the works and is it possible to start testing it yet?

Comment: Why do you ask here? I suggest you ask "Deezer" if they offer such thing?

Comment: Deezer direct all support questions to Stack Overflow with the deezer tag, which is what I've done.

Comment: What a lazy bunch. One reason more not to use their service.

Answer (score 0):

We have a fallback on a HTML5 player for now, but it is not built in order to play full tracks. You can test if you want.Also, this problem will occur only for ads.